# Terminal abnormal behaviour on resize

Tags: gnome-terminal

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on my machine. On resizing the terminal from big size to small size it's showing some abnormal behavior. It just repeats the line n times. Is there anything wrong with the settings I made? Or is it happening with everyone.?[image]

Comment: See my comment at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vte2.91/+bug/1927063 for explanation.

Comment: @egmont it would be worthwhile to copy your comment here as a very valid answer to the how and why of this behavior.

Comment: The terminal kitty apparently has a way to handle this.